# Как сделать функцию для переключения музыки в системе через python

Tags: python, клавиатура

**У многих ноутбуков есть функциональные клавиши и мне нужно чтобы я мог переключить музыку как они это делают в python** *пробовал записать через библиотеку keyboard и воспроизвести но вот они не считает нажатие этих клавиш*

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго искал название этой клавиши но все оказалось очень просто

```
 import keyboard
    help(keyboard)
    keyboard.send("next track")
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).